# Would doing Kegel exercise by hanging weight to penis is really effective?

Tags: exercise, muscle, penis, home-medical-equipment

An advertisement of a Kegel equipment for men claims that hanging more weight to the erected penis while contracting the pubococcygeus muscle will help make it stronger. Superficially, this makes sense to me, since to make any muscle stronger, forcing it work more intense than everyday is necessary. Here is their visualization:

[image]

But is there any scientific paper research on this method?

The only article that the advertisement refers to is [Pelvic Exercises for Men, Too](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2014/07/14/pelvic-exercises-for-men-too/?_r=0), which 1) seems to promote the aforementioned company, and 2) doesn't actually cite any paper that seems to answer the efficiency of the product. [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/urinary-incontinence-oab/kegel-exercises-treating-male-urinary-incontinence) and [Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/mens-health/in-depth/kegel-exercises-for-men/art-20045074) do not specially mention about adding more weight to the penis.

Comment: You're looking for scientific evidence to support ridiculous claims made by people selling ridiculous products and you want us to watch a video they made? Not happening.

Comment: I just want to have more knowledge. What's wrong with that?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your question, but I don't think the video is necessary to understand it. Since the video is an ad for a product, I don't think it's appropriate.

Comment: Ah, it's just a reference. You can say that it's just a habit of citing. I have opened a meta question regarding on this: [When asking about an advertised method, does refering to it necessary?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/659/99)